# Is there a way to load static language files and also be able to load additional language resource on-demand using ngx-translator?

Tags: angular, localization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n, ngx-translate-multi-http-loader

My application has static JSON files for most translations, but some run time data also has translations and I'd like to load that translation data on-demand using ngx-translator.

Is there a way to load static files and also be able to load additional data on-demand?